# can't do sudo nautilus on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, xorg

After having updated to 17.10 I noticed a problem to run sudo nautilus.
In user mode it works

```
ilan@ilan-Desktop:~$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
^C
ilan@ilan-Desktop:~$ sudo nautilus
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:27798): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I tried to look around and found https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230828
There is a suggestion that perhaps xorg.conf is causing problems but I see no such file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d. There is xorg.conf.failsafe from April 2016.

Thanks for any suggestions,
Ilan

Comment: This refers to Wayland which I am not using. The link was useful in that it suggests I should use gksu instead of sudo. This I tried and it gave me a dialog box where I should be able to type in my pass word. Unfortunately I couldn't get the text box the focus. The result is ilan@ilan-Desktop:~$ gksu nautilus
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant

Comment: Sorry, I had never heard the name Wayland and didn't know it was the default. I thought I was still in the familiar Xorg, but apparently not. My bad.

Comment: You can check which session you are in by running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

Comment: Once I understood that I was using Wayland, I tried xhost si:localuser:root and it did the trick. So it is a duplicate. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry I missed what you were saying the first time around.